# Call action from another Controller

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I have a controller action.How can i call action method from another controller in asp.net mvc?

Is this a valid thing to do. Is it possible?

Comment: what does action.How returns? a view, a partial view or a Json object?

Comment: You didn't answer my question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're first action is complete then you might redirect to another action.

If there is some common code between these two controllers that you don't want to duplicate then you'd probably look at creating a service which would have this and be called by both actions